# django FileField and data migrations

Tags: django

So I added a `FileField` to my model:

```
def sig_directory_path(instance, filename):
    try:
        ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    except:
        ext = ""
    filename = '{}.{}'.format(uuid4().hex, ext)
    return 'sig/{0}'.format(filename)

ServiceReportData(models.Model):
    ...
    # Newly added.
    ca_technicianSignatureImage = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Technician Signature", upload_to=sig_directory_path)
```

I already created the auto migration and migrated the changes. So the DB now has `null` values for `ca_technicianSignatureImage` column.

Then I wanted to create a data migration for this field because I don't want null values for the field:

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.db import migrations


# File content.

no_image_svg_content = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
version="1.1"
width="200"
height="150">
<rect
width="199"
height="149"
x="0.5"
y="0.5"
id="rect2824"
fill="#ffffff" stroke="#999999" stroke-width="1"/>
<text
x="64.648438"
y="79.863152"
id="text2818"
font-size="24"
font-weight="bold" text-align="center" text-anchor="middle" fill="#999999" stroke="none" font-family="Sans">
<tspan
x="100"
y="60"
id="tspan2820">No image</tspan>
<tspan
x="100"
y="90"
id="tspan2822">available</tspan>
</text>
</svg>
"""


def set_signatures(apps, schema_editor):
    no_image_data = ContentFile(no_image_svg_content)
    ServiceReportData = apps.get_model('mism', 'ServiceReportData')
    for service_report in ServiceReportData.objects.all():
        if service_report.ca_customerSignatureImage is None:
            service_report.ca_customerSignatureImage.save('no_image.svg', no_image_data)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('mism', '0004_auto_20180131_1651'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(set_signatures, migrations.RunPython.noop),
    ]
```

Running this migration doesn't change the DB. I can't figure out how to do it. Simply, I just want to put a default .svg file in the field if the field is empty. How to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug after all was simple.

This is not the correct way to check if a FileField is null:

```
if service_report.ca_customerSignatureImage is None:
```

Rather had to do this:

```
if service_report.ca_customerSignatureImage.name is None:
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call instance's save() method also:

```
service_report.ca_customerSignatureImage.save('no_image.svg', no_image_data)
service_report.save()
```

or as a shortcut use [`save=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.File.save) of File save method:

```
service_report.ca_customerSignatureImage.save('no_image.svg', no_image_data, save=True)
```

Comment: Ok, now at least the DB field updates. But it's updated with an empty string.

Comment: @nakiya your new column is ca_technicianSignatureImage so you need to use it inslead of ca_customerSignatureImage: `service_report.ca_technicianSignatureImage.save('no_image.svg', no_image_data, save=True)`

Comment: Turns out it was a stupid error. Had to debug to find out. This check never passes: `if service_report.ca_customerSignatureImage is None:`